# How to split a dataframe column in python. (Data from Qyandl)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, split

I download some data from Quandl.
The dataentered as a DataFrame but with a wrong format:

```
In [81]: a
Out[81]: 
                RATE
DATE                
2000-01-01  1.806020
2000-01-02  1.804029
2000-01-03  1.809771
2000-01-04  1.829093
```

This data frame is float64 and has only one column

```
list(a.columns.values)
Out[83]: ['RATE']

a.RATE
Out[85]: 
DATE
2000-01-01    1.806020
2000-01-02    1.804029
2000-01-03    1.809771
2000-01-04    1.829093
```

Name: RATE, dtype: float64

I need to split it into DATE and RATE columns.

So far I was only able to find solutions like

```
a.str.split('    ', expand=True)
```

or

```
a['RATE'].str.contains('....-..-..', regex=True).
```

But whenever I run this I get:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

How can i split this single column to obtain a DataFrame with Date and Rate columns instead?

Thanks
Pavel

Answer (score 3):

you can use [reset_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) function:

```
In [128]: df.reset_index()
Out[128]:
        DATE      RATE
0 2000-01-01  1.806020
1 2000-01-02  1.804029
2 2000-01-03  1.809771
3 2000-01-04  1.829093
```